# What event to use in datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have a datetimepicker using for filtering the datagridivew using a from to code. This is my code for filtering [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqeiN.jpg). And event of my datetimepicker is ValueChanged. I want to trigger this code when i click a date from my datetimepicker, but when i click the same date from my datetimepicker it doesnt filter the datagridview. Example If the value of my DTP is 2019-11-15 and i need to filter my datagridview from 2019-11-15 i need to set my datetimepicker to 2019-11-15 but since its the same value it does not filter my datagridvuew

I want to only filter my datagridview when i click a date from my datetimepicker.

```
WHERE Date >= '" & DateTimePicker4.text & '" and Date <= '" & DateTimePicker3.Text & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the .Text property will not do the work here. Use

> DateTimePicker4.Value

and there are more options under that Value property that you can use.